# Undamped, Forced Vibrations amplitude and period

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, mathematical-modeling

Task says that forced vibration of a point described by second order differential equation: $$x''(t)+x(t)=8\sin{3t}-4\cos4t$$ and initial conditions $x(0)=0; x'(0)=3$.
I already have solved this equation. First of all I found solution of homogeneous differential equation $x''+x=0$ and secondly I have found some particular solution. 
So I get the solution: $$x(t)=\frac{4\cos4t}{15} - \sin3t-\frac{4\cos t}{15}+6\sin t$$ 
Now, I should find the period and amplitude and really need help with it. I found these formulas: $c=\sqrt{c1+c2}$-amplitude, here $c1=6$ and $c2=\frac{4}{15}$ from the initial conditions and $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$-period, but not sure are they correct in this situation. Please advice. (also here is a graph of displacement vs time. I believe we can see amplitude and period from the graph, but I must calculate it exactly). [image]

Comment: The factor periods are rational...

Comment: ok, I found this formula, maybe you then have some suggestions how to calculate there? @Cesareo

Comment: I doubt a closed form for the amplitude can be found, because equation $x'(t)=0$ cannot be solved exactly.

Comment: @Aretino Yes, I also see problem in this case. But what about the period?

Comment: The period is simply the LCM of the four periods, hence $2\pi$.

Comment: @Aretino thank you